# Replacing an Object in an array with updated version of itself

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
        Match *aMatch = [appDelegate.matchScoresArray 
objectAtIndex:numMatchCounter];
        aMatch.teamName2 = TeamNameHolder;
        [appDelegate.matchScoresArray replaceObjectAtIndex:NumMatchCounter 
withObject:aMatch];
        numMatchCounter++;
```

Does this make sense or is the change i made to teamName2 already reflected in the array, since they are the same object?

Or am I right to copy the object over itself back into the array.

I'm really confused.

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should grab the object from the array and update it. There is no need to copy over it.

You can grab a reference to the object and update it. The variable aMatch points to the same memory location as the object referenced in your array.

The following should be fine:

```
Match *aMatch = [appDelegate.matchScoresArray 
objectAtIndex:numMatchCounter];
        aMatch.teamName2 = TeamNameHolder;
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to copy the object back into the array.  The array holds a refernece to the object. aA long as the object instnace remains the same there is no need to copy it back after changing it's properties.